# How to force landscape orientation in a webapp in the browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, orientation

I have a webapp that is running in the chrome web browser on Android.
I want to lock the orientation to landscape.

I tried several options according to [this](https://code-boxx.com/lock-screen-orientation/#sec-rotate) tutorial:
using ScreenOrientation.lock(), which is experimental.
The example code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/f7nurLtj/5/) does not work in my mobile phone (Pixel3, Android 11) - when the device is rotated, the orientation changes.

I also tried a CSS trick, which rotates the screen by 90 degrees, if it detect that the device is in portrait mode.
The screen is rendered in landscape mode [in the simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/f7nurLtj/1/), but the functionality of the real application is broken. For example, when moving the finger in the x direction is interpreted as moving in y direction.

[Other](https://jsfiddle.net/avnerm/f7nurLtj/15/) tries also failed on my Pixel3 phone in Chrome in Android (when rotating the device the orientation changes)

I am able to lock the orientation by installing the page as a PWA "Add to Home Screen" and using a manifest with

```
cat manifest.json
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape",
```

But this requires that the user installs the app as a [PWA](https://love2dev.com/pwa/web-manifest/)

I want to lock the orientation of the webapp while it is running in the regular browser.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best bet you could do is generate a simple `popup` that disallows input, ie; covering the screen. Then use the following code [which can be better fine-tuned] to detect if the user is in portrait or landscape mode.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    document.body.getElementById('custom-popup').classList.add('show');
    // Obviously you'd have to make a popup that is visible when the class 'custom-popup` is added.
  } else {
    document.body.getElementById('custom-popup').classList.remove('show');
    // The user switched to landscape presumably
  }
}, 3000);
```